# AWS UserData Script in RedHat 7 EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, ec2-userdata

I am loading userdata script using AWC CDK typescript code as below.

```
let userDataScript = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./lib/helpers/bootstrap.sh"), "utf8");
  
instance.addUserData(userDataScript);
```

The script runs only partially and doesn't seem to run below statements as I see :
No jq pacakage available message in logs.

```
echo "Installing epel release"  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 

yes | rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 

echo "Finished Installing epel release"  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 


echo "Installing yum update"  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 
yum -y update   >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 

echo "Finished Installing yum update"  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 


echo "Installing  jq"  >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log 
yum -y install jq   >>  /tmp/cfn-init.log
```

Strange part being, if I run these commands from console using SSM session manager, everything works as expected. Any suggestions please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing carriage return (\r) from the shell script helped to resolve the issue.